# Authy: Do cloud backups update automatically after each added 2-factor account

Tags: multi-factor

I read the Authy docs about how the cloud back up works.  But there is one thing I'm unclear on.

Do you have to manually disable and re-enable cloud backup, and set up a new one after each time you add a new 2 factor account?  For example: If I set up cloud backups for my 1 existing facebook 2 factor account, I then 1 month later add google 2 factor to Authy, do I then have to manually create an entirely new cloud backup for it to be up to date?

I would hope it's automatic, but that would mean the PBKDF2 hash derived from the originally entered password, which is never sent to Authy, is actually stored on the local device in order to re-encrypt a backup in the event new 2 factor accounts are added or removed.

Please advise.  Thanks.

Comment: this is a question for their support and/or docs